# How to combine multiple .OBJ point cloud files into one point cloud?

Tags: point-clouds

I noticed that we can combine multiple OBJ meshes with [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/merging-multiple-obj-files), but I don't know how to do this with point clouds. I have several point clouds that represent partial scans of an object and I wanted to drag these together to recombine them into one full scan of the object. Can I do this with Blender?

Comment: Hello :). I don't see why not. The linked answer should work well. If you ran into any trouble, feel free to post a new question.